# I know of a case that is in mediation in Taiwan what details can I find out about it?

Tags: contract-law, international, mediation

I am an English tutor and my student told me about contract that is in mediation- his company is Japanese and the other party (company) is American- listed on the stock exchange. Would some of the details be on public record? How do I find those details? I just want to know before I share any details with anyone. Do international contract mediation proceedings result in any publicly available documentation?

Comment: If you rephrase the question to ask if international contract mediation proceedings result in any publicly available documentation you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mediation is a private and explicitly confidential process - it is unlikely that any information is public.

In fact, one of the main reasons people choose Alternative Dispute Resolution like mediation is that it allows them to keep private the fact that they are having a dispute.

Comment: I was thinking like that but wouldn't the fact that there is a dispute be on some public record.

Comment: No, one of the main reasons people choose ADR like mediation is to keep private the fact that there is a dispute at all.